# How to design in android using RelativeLayout without using some static margin for all screen density

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

Here is my `Layout` code(xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/common_bg"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnHolderRelLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notificationBtn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
        android:baselineAligned="@+id/button4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <!-- android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scheduledBtn" -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pendingBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pending_select_bg"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/pending_txt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <!-- android:layout_centerInParent="true" -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scheduledBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/scheduled_deselect_bg"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:text="@string/scheduled_txt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <!-- android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/scheduledBtn"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scheduledBtn"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scheduledBtn" -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/completedBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/completed_deselect_bg"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:text="@string/completed_txt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notificationBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notifications_icon"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commonFragmentListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnHolderRelLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/content_bg"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_appointment"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is ok in 480 X 800 devices but in bigger screen everything is messed up coz I m using a static margin `android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"` for `notificationBtn`.

```
How can I design this Screen like below screen shot without using any static margin or view's height and width
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: create multiple dimens for different devices.http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/common_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pendingBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scheduledBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/pending_select_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/pending_txt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scheduledBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scheduled_deselect_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/scheduled_txt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/completedBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scheduledBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/completed_deselect_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/completed_txt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notificationBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scheduledBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/notifications_icon"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commonFragmentListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pendingBtn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/content_bg"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_appointment"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use screen height and width at runtime to decide padding , margin size etc
```

Like

// Define this in some constant file as final variable.

```
Display mDisplay= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth= mDisplay.getWidth();
int screenHeight= mDisplay.getHeight();
```

Now you can you it.

```
PADDING_SIZE_SMALL = screenHeight * (0.1) // 10% percent of screen height 
PADDING_SIZE_LARGE  = screenHeight * (0.25) // 25% percent of screen height 
PADDING_SIZE_MEDIUM  = screenHeight * (0.15) // 15% percent of screen height 

MARGIN_SIZE_SMALL = screenHeight * (0.1) // 10% percent of screen height 
MARGIN_SIZE_LARGE  = screenHeight * (0.25) // 25% percent of screen height 
MARGIN_SIZE_MEDIUM  = screenHeight * (0.15) // 15% percent of screen height 

HEADER_TEXT_SMALL =  screenHeight * (0.25)  25% percent of screen height 
HEADER_TEXT_LARGE =   screenHeight * (0.35) 35% percent of screen height 

LEFT_BAR_WIDTH = screenWidth * (0.45) 45% percent of screen width
```

Now you can set all this value attribute pragmatically to any element ListView. TextView or Layout also.

This is logical way of supporting Android UI Design: Supporting Multiple Screens.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/common_bg"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/notificationPendingBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/notifications_icon"
                android:text="6"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pendingBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/pending_select_bg"
                android:text="@string/pending_txt"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/notificationScheduledBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/notifications_icon"
                android:text="6"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/scheduledBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/scheduled_deselect_bg"
                android:text="@string/scheduled_txt"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/notificationCompletedBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/notifications_icon"
                android:text="6"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/completedBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/completed_deselect_bg"
                android:text="@string/completed_txt"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commonFragmentListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/content_bg"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_appointment"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```